# How can use buttons on devexpress Edit Form for execute some extra code

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-gridcontrol

I have DevExpress GridControl with customized edit form for update or adding rows in VB.net.
And the Problem:
1-When user click on Update button on popup edit form, how can execute some extra code with this event. for example do some thing in database and est.
2-how can change the name and visibility of standard buttons on edit form?
Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will want to handle the GridView's [EditFormPrepared](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.EditFormPrepared.event) event to modify the controls within your custom edit form. For instance:

```
    private void gvEmployees_EditFormPrepared(object sender, EditFormPreparedEventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler UpdateButton_Click = null;
    var updateButton = e.Panel.Controls.OfType<PanelControl>().FirstOrDefault().Controls.OfType<SimpleButton>().Select(x => x.Text == GridLocalizer.Active.GetLocalizedString(GridStringId.EditFormUpdateButton) ? x : null).FirstOrDefault();

    updateButton.Text = "My new button text";

    UpdateButton_Click = (s, eventarg) =>
    {
        //Your code here
    };

    updateButton.Click += UpdateButton_Click;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. when I convert the code to vb.net, I got error with last line of code. would you please check it?

Comment: In VB.NET you would want to use the [RemoveHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/removehandler-statement) function.